# Error loading data with too many levels/categories h2o.importFile()

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to import a large .csv file using h2o.importfile in R

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
dataFile <- "big_file.csv" 
h2o.importFile(dataFile,header=TRUE,destination_frame = "data.hex")
```

The file has a number of id columns. I get the following error message.

***Error: water.parser.ParseDataset$H2OParseException: Exceeded categorical limit on columns [id1, id2]. Consider reparsing these columns as a string.***

Is there way to specify these colum types to be strings similar to data.frame(stringAsFactors = FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the `col.types` argument in `h2o.importFile` function should work for you.

```
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")
hf0 <- h2o.importFile("iris.csv", col.types = c("int","real","real","real","real","string"))
unlist(h2o.getTypes(hf0))
[1] "int"    "real"   "real"   "real"   "real"   "string"
```